# Why am I unable to overwrite a variable in a loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Variable `hey` should be overwritten when I go through the for-loop, so if I don't enter 1, it says "bye", but then if I enter 1 when it goes through the loop, it should say "hello", but instead it's saying "bye".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char hey;
    for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++){
        cout << "enter 1" << endl;
        cin >> hey;
        if (hey == 1)
                cout << "hello\n";
        else
            cout << "bye";
    }
}
```

Comment: `1` is not the same as `'1'`.

Answer (score 1):

The character `'1'` with ASCII numer 49 is different from the number 1.
Use

```
if (hey == '1')
```

If you want to compare something to the character a, you´ll have to use `'a'` too. It´s the same here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `hey` is of type `char`.  Therefore the input read from the console is interpreted as a `char`.  You can either make the comparison  `if (hey == '1')` or change the type of `hey` to something such as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `char hey` to `int hey`. It will work as you expect.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @KenY-N: Actually, it is an answer. This will cause `operator<<(int&)` to be called.

Answer (score 0):

If the user enters '1', char will be the character code for '1', which is 49.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60ecse8t(v=vs.80).aspx

You could change your code to either

```
if (hey == '1')
```

or

```
if (hey == 49)
```

The title for this post is incorrect, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing Ascii character value to Integer . Ascii value of  1 is 49