# Is there some way to stop initializing a character array using an appropriate boolean condition inside of an If statement in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to get a user to populate a character array up to 10 letters, but they should (in theory) be able to stop entering letters at any time. Said differently, if a user wants to only enter 5 letters, they should be able to.

My question is how can I use some sort of expression structure like if-else branches to exit the for loop shown below that initializes and populates the array?

```
#include <iostream>

const int DECLARED_SIZE = 10; //max size of an array in the main

void fillUpArray(char array[], int size, int& actual_size);
void reverseArray(char array[], int actual_size);

int main()
{
  char letters[DECLARED_SIZE];
  int actualSize;

  fillUpArray(letters, DECLARED_SIZE, actualSize);
  reverseArray(letters, actualSize);

}

void fillUpArray(char array[], int size, int& actual_size) //here is where my question is!
{
  int index;
  char letter;
    std::cout << "Enter up to " << size << " letters. Enter something the loop to stop\n";
    for(index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
    std::cin >> letter; 
    if(letter == something that stops this loop)
      break;
    else
          array[index] = letter;
    }
    
    actual_size = index;
}

void reverseArray(char array[], int actual_size)
{
  int index;
  for(index = actual_size; index >= 0; index--)
  {
    std::cout << array[index] << "\t";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You should really be using `std::string` instead of a `char[]`, it'll make things much easier for you.

Comment: Or, at the very least, `std::cin.getline()`, with an optional delimiter if something other than ENTER (`'\n'`).

Comment: @cigien I know the string class has more functionality but for a class study code it gets the job done I like to think for a simple case as printing out the reverse of a collection of letters. But I would love to know why you think since I'm still new to this stuff!

Comment: The very fact that `string` has more functionality is the reason to use it. Simple things should be simple to write, and `string` is simpler and less error prone than `char` arrays.

Comment: @cigien did you see any 'errors' in the code around character array? IMO, string vs character array should be a programmer's choice. You may want to avoid arrays but another might prefer it to strings.

Comment: @banal Sure, it's up to a programmer what tools they want to use (barring external constraints). It's just my opinion that `string`s are the better tool in a vast majority of cases, *especially* for programmers who are not that familiar with the language.

Comment: Use `cin.get()` and check if the character is `'\n'` to end input, e.g. `std::string s {}; char c;` then simply `while (std::cin.get(c) && c != '\n') s.push_back(c);` done. Your input is in `s` and you no longer have to worry about array overrun.

Comment: Since the answer to your question is in your code (`if(letter == something that stops this loop) break;` is "some sort of expression structure like if-else branches to exit the for loop"), I think this question warrants being closed because it fails to accurately describe the problem.

Comment: You have an error in your code: if you run the `for` loop in `fillUpArray()` to the end, the `index` will be equal to `size`, causing out-of-bounds reference in `reverseArray`. Also, you are NOT reversing the array, you are printing its content in reverse order. My intuition tells me that it's not what you are supposed to do.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so I used a period `'.'` inside the `if` statement inside the function `fillUpArray()`, but why does a period character work and not say something like a number?

Comment: You are reading input character-by-character. You can use any character you want to stop the loop. A number would certainly work fine too, you would just have to test for it explicitly, just like you do with `'.'`, eg: `if (letter >= '0' && letter <= '9')` instead of `if (letter == '.')`.  In this case, `'\n'` would probably make more sense, then the user can simply press ENTER when they are done entering their input.

Comment: You have failed to mention *how* you used a period and how you tried using "something like a number", but most likely: [Why am I unable to overwrite a variable in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039849/)